# Debug python (in Docker) from VS Code

Tags: python, docker, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have a python application with various dependencies that get resolved during `docker-compose build` command. A docker image is created, and when run it's a simple REST API that I can access via a browser.

I want to send a GET request and then debug the corresponding method in VS Code. However I'm struggling to get this to work. I'm able to get the docker image running from within VS Code (using `Remote-Containers: Open Folder in Container` option). I can see the API is up and changes in the code are reflected live.

However I'm struggling to get the debugging part to work. 
When I start debugging, I'm asked to provide a Debug Configuration and I'm not sure what the right one to pick or how to set one up....

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [documentation on debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) on how to create a debug configuration.